# Electric field of a black hole with charges fall into from opposite directions

Tags: black-holes, electric-fields, charge, reissner-nordstrom-metric

Take a black hole, drop in some protons into end and some electrons into the point directly opposite.

I am having a great deep of trouble understanding why this doesn’t turn the black hole into an electric Dipole.

Comment: Do you think they stay separated?

Comment: Neither fall in from the perspective of outside observers

Comment: True, but then you didn’t drop them “into” the hole.

Comment: Except they are being dropped into the hole.

Comment: @blademan9999 The radius of the horizon is timelike - the opposite points on the horizon are separated by time, not by space.